# Class does not implement interface member because it does not have matching return type

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Implementing a service for ASP.NET core Web API app and getting a persistent error.

1. The error still occurs even if I just implement the interface without adding any additional code to the methods.
2. I've checked, double checked, and even triple checked all the signatures to make sure no typos.
3. Tried making GetUserInvite function an IEnumerable after looking at other SO threads. Still no luck.

Interface:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using API.Data.Dtos.InviteDto;
using API.Domain;

namespace API.Services
{
    public interface IInviteService
    {
        Task<UserInvite> GetUserInvite(Guid sourceUserId, Guid invitedUserId);
        Task<IEnumerable<InviteDto>> GetUserInvites(string predicate, Guid userId);
        Task<User> GetUserWithInvites(Guid userId);
    }
}
```

Service:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using API.Data;
using API.Data.Dtos.InviteDto;
using API.Domain;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace API.Services
{
    public class InviteService : IInviteService
    {
        private readonly DataContext _context;
        public InviteService(DataContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public async Task<UserInvite> GetUserInvite(Guid sourceUserId, Guid invitedUserId)
        {
            return await _context.Invites.FindAsync(sourceUserId, invitedUserId);
        }

        public async Task<User> GetUserWithInvites(Guid userId)
        {
            return await _context.Users.Include(x => x.InvitedUsers).FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == userId);
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<InviteDto>> GetUserInvites(string predicate, Guid userId)
        {
            var users = _context.Users.OrderBy(u => u.UserName).AsQueryable();
            var invites = _context.Invites.AsQueryable();

            if (predicate == "invited")
            {
                invites = invites.Where(invite => invite.SourceUserId == userId);
                users = invites.Select(invite => invite.InvitedUser);
            }

            if (predicate == "invitedBy")
            {
                invites = invites.Where(invite => invite.InvitedUserId == userId);
                users = invites.Select(invite => invite.SourceUser);
            }

            return await users.Select(user => new InviteDto
            {
                Username = user.UserName,
                City = user.City
            }).ToListAsync();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You code return types is either IEnumerable<InviteDto> or UserInvite.  So the query that is being returned from the database isn't matching one of the two types.

Comment: Rather than trying to be very sure that you've written out the signatures correctly, just let VS auto generate them by choosing that option from the error and then you don't need to worry about trying to figure out what the difference is.

Comment: @jdweng error occurs before compilation so database never gets interacted with. Console error says issue is with GetUserInvite as well.

Comment: @Servy I've actually tried generating the code with VS (and just have the throw exception boilerplate code as well) and it still does the same issue.

Comment: Is code in different modules?  The using statements are not the same in both modules.

Comment: See following to impliment IEnumerable<T> : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2017/june/essential-net-custom-iterators-with-yield

Answer (score 0):

The issue was an error in VS. I restarted and everything compiled. Thank you to all those that helped.